# my HTML Shortcuts in VS Code are not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I started studying HTML on YouTube not long ago and have been using visual studio code. Whenever specific shortcuts are used, mine does not work. An example would be typing the exclamation mark and then the tab button("!" + tab) to automatically give you the default HTML skeletal template.
Also, tag suggestions do not work. Whenever I start to type a tag like , I don't get any suggestions whatsoever and it leads to a lot of mistakes and confusion for me. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You need to tell VSC what type of document you're working on first, for example HTML. Hit control K +M and then type HTML to set the document type and then the suggestions and [Emmet shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) will work

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me to the bottom of VS Code, where I changed Django-HTML to HTML to get the doc shortcut to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to VS code and tap on setting will show a pop-up, choose Keyboard Shortcut will showcase you all the keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. `CTRL + Shift + P`
2. Change language mode
3. Click on "Configure file association for .html"
4. If you scroll down through the list, you will see a label "Current association" next to the file type that your file is currently associated to.
5. Change it to .HTML if that's what you want .html files to be associated to.
6. Close the file and open it again.
7. Try `!` - a tooltip should now pop up and then you hit `tab`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change languague on status bar (below) from Django html to html.

Now retype the shortcut i.e. "!+Enter"

Answer (score 0):

**Change Setting Emmet**

1. Go to Setting , <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for shortcut
2. Type Emmet Tab on search bar
3. Enable trigger expansion on tab
4. Try type <kbd>!</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

**Suggest**

1. Type <kbd>!</kbd> on HTML File
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, to activate trigger suggest
3. And Enter

**HTML:5**

1. Type html:5
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>